# Haskell code: how to skip every other number in a list of primes

Tags: haskell

The objective is to get a list of primes that skips every other prime number. An example would be primeskip 10 --> [2,5,11,17,23,31,41,47,59,67]. I am pretty sure my prime function works but I am doing something wrong in the skip.

This is the code that I have.

```
isPrime n = ip n [2..(n `div` 2)]
    where
    ip _ [] = True
    ip n (x:xs)
        | n `mod` x == 0 = False
        | otherwise = ip n xs

primeskip :: Int -> [Int]
primeskip n = take n [x | x <- [2,5..], isPrime x]
```

I tried to mess around with the filter command but I don't know what I am doing. I am very new to Haskall and functional languages. I got the result of [2,5,11,17,23,29,41,47,53,59] when entering primeskip 10 which doesn't skip properly at 23 to 29.

Comment: What exactly do you think `[2,5..]` does? Once you have an answer, try it in ghci, and see if what ghci does matches your guess.

Comment: I assumed that is would skip every other prime for me. And my result sort of did that but it messed up at 23-29.

Comment: @IdiotStump: no, it is a linear list, so `[2,5,8,11,14,...]`, it thus does steps of three.

Comment: Number 3 is prime, but you filter it out. Just use [2..] instead [2,5..], for instance.

Comment: As for prime numbers, there is a lot of available work [here on the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers). Next, you can create some general purpose function that skips every other item on *any* list, and combine it with your chosen prime number generation algorithm.

Comment: @IdiotStump I understand what your assumption was, and I was gently trying to hint at ways you could test that assumption (and find it false, by the by).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility consists in developing separately:

1. a generic function that skips every 2nd element in any list
2. a function that generates a list of all prime numbers

and then combine these two things in our very last step.
This is consistent with the commonly held piece of engineering philosophy:

“*Do just one thing but do it well.*”

As for the first step, we can use recursion:

```
everyOther :: [a] -> [a]
everyOther (x:y:zs) = x : everyOther zs
everyOther [x]      = [x]
everyOther []       = []
```

Regarding the computation of the list of all prime numbers, the [Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers) displays a large number of possibilities.

We have to note that the approach of testing primality separately for every single number is massively inefficient. One gains a lot by leveraging the list of *previous* prime numbers. It is for example redundant to divide a candidate prime by non-prime numbers. A possible code which avoids these drawbacks goes for example like this:

```
-- limit the search to possible prime factors, below the square root of
-- the candidate:
getBound :: Int -> Int -> Int
getBound n b = let  b1 = b+1
               in   if (b1*b1 > n)  then  b  else  getBound n b1

findNextPrime :: Int -> Int -> Int
findNextPrime k b = if (all (\p -> mod k p /= 0) $ takeWhile (<= b) allPrimes)
                         then  k
                         else  findNextPrime (k+1) (getBound (k+1) b)

genPrimes :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
genPrimes k bound =
    let  np = findNextPrime k (getBound k bound)
    in   np : genPrimes (np+1) (getBound (np+1) bound)

allPrimes :: [Int]
allPrimes = 2 : (genPrimes 3 1)
```

Finally, we can combine the two above functionalities:

```
primeSkip :: Int -> [Int]
primeSkip n = take n $ everyOther allPrimes
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to generate the *odd* integers, since even numbers are by definition not prime, while odd integers may or may not be prime. You could could prepend `2` to the list of candidates

```
primeskip n = take n [x | x <- (2:[3,5..]), isPrime x]
```

but it might be simpler to just prepend it to the result to avoid testing it, as you consider *because* you know already know it is prime.

```
primeskip n = 2 : (take (n-1) [x | x <- [3,5..], isPrime x])
```