# Haskell - function that returns the sum of all prime divisors of a given number

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, primes

this is my code, but it gives me an infinitive loop. i can't find my mistake, can you help me and give me some advices to find it?

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n = n > 1 && helper 2
 where
    helper d
     | d >= n = True
     | mod n d == 0 = False
     | otherwise = helper (d + 1)

sumPrimeDivs :: Int -> Int
sumPrimeDivs n = helper n 2 0
 where
    helper num d result
     |isPrime d && mod num d == 0  = helper num (d + 1) result + d
     |d == num = result
     |otherwise = helper num (d + 1) result
```

I have to find the sum of all prime divisors of a given number.

Comment: Further, in the last helper function the arguments `num` and `result` never change during recursion, so you can omit them and use `n` and `0` instead.

Comment: I don't know whether this is the root cause, but it is very inefficient to test **all** numbers below num as possible divisors. You could look at the [relevant wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers) or [SO question 75198070](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75198070) for ideas. It might help to have a (lazy) list of all prime numbers as an auxiliary quantity.

Comment: If the input is 36, is the expected output 2+3 or 2+2+3+3 ?

Comment: it has to be 2 + 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the last helper function. Sometimes we call `helper p p result` where the two first arguments are the same prime `p`. This falls in the first case of the definition

```
 |isPrime d && mod num d == 0  = helper num (d + 1) result + d
```

This makes a recursive call to the helper with `helper p (p+1) result` but now the second argument is too large to trigger the termination condition

```
 |d == num = result
```

Change that to `d >= num` instead.

Further in the helper you never change the first and third arguments, so you can omit them. For instance:

```
sumPrimeDivs :: Int -> Int
sumPrimeDivs n = helper 2
 where
    helper d
     | isPrime d && mod n d == 0 = helper (d + 1) + d
     | d >= n                    = 0
     | otherwise                 = helper (d + 1)
```

(Personally, I'd write the code differently, reordering the cases, making use of list comprehensions, or even using a more efficient algorithm, but I wanted to preserve your original code as much as possible here.)

Alternatively, you might have wanted to use `result` as an accumulator, but in that case you need to call `helper (d+1) (result+d)` when you recurse.

Comment: thank you, everything is correct now!